# Android RecyclerView item reorder infinite loop issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm having a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. I've implemented item reordering so user can reorder the items using `ItemTouchHelper` & `SimpleCallback`.

But there is a problem of infinite loop when reordering.
To better understand the issue, see the attached video:
[image]

The code for reordering is as follows:

```kotlin
override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
): Boolean {
    val from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    val to = target.adapterPosition
    val newSwitches = switches.toMutableList()
    // 1
    if (from < to) for (i in from until to) Collections.swap(newSwitches, i, i + 1)
    else for (i in from downTo to + 1) Collections.swap(newSwitches, i, i - 1)
    // Or 2
    Collections.swap(newList, from, to)
    setSwitches(newSwitches)
    return true
}
```

In code above, approach 1 as well as 2 results in an infinite loop issue as shown in video.

When I print `from` & `to` values to console they're like:

```
from: 10, to: 11
from: 11, to: 10
from: 10, to: 11
from: 11, to: 10
and so on...
```

PS: I'm using edge-to-edge to draw behind system bars & applying extra padding to the RecyclerView with `clipChildren="false"` & `clipToPadding="false"`. Could the issued be due to this?

Edit 1:
`setSwitches(newSwitches)` uses `DiffUtil`.